# lapply and interp (akima)

Tags: r, interpolation, lapply

I'd like to interpolate over many individual `data.frames` stored within a `list` using the `akima` package.

Having split my original data frame:

```
store <- split(data, data$frameID)
```

I tried this...

```
 results <- lapply(store, interp, x = lon, y = lat, z = precip)
```

But I get the error message `Error in interp(x = lon, y = lat, z = precip) : object 'lat' not found`.

Single results can be **successfully** generated with the following..

```
results <-list() # create and empty list for results

results[[i]]<-with(store$`600`, interp(x = lon, y = lat, z = precip)).
```

Where `600` represents the name of one of the `data.frames` within the list.

However attempting to generalise to the entire list using a loop-approach..

```
i=1

for (i in i:length(store)){
  results[[i]]<-with(store$`i`, interp(x = lon, y = lat, z = precip))
 }
```

I again receive `Error in interp(x = lon, y = lat, z = precip) : object 'lat' not found`.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: is it possible that one of your `data.frames` within the list is missing `lat`?

Comment: try `with(store[[i]], ...)` ...

Comment: you can go ahead and post your solution as an answer.  It's better to do that than to edit it into your question ...

Answer (score 1):

Using the suggestions, and accounting for duplicate points (same lat and lon for some stations) this does the job.

```
i=1

for (i in i:length(store)){
  results[[i]]<-with(store[[i]], interp(x = lon, y = lat, z = precip,
duplicate = "mean"))
}
```